Is this Result on Continuity of Composite functions true?
Consider,
A real valued function $f(x)$ which is discontinuous $\hspace{2mm}\forall \hspace{2mm} x \in [\alpha,\beta]$ and another real valued function $g(x)$ which is discontinuous $\hspace{2mm}\forall \hspace{2mm} x \in [\epsilon,\delta]$ then,
The function $f(g(x))$ is discontinuous $\hspace{2mm} \forall \hspace{2mm} x \in [\epsilon,\delta] \hspace{2mm}\cup \hspace{1mm} \eta$
where $\eta=\left\{x:x=g^{-1}(a), a\in A,A=[\alpha,\beta]\right\}$
for example, consider,
$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-11)(x-6)}$ and $g(x)=\frac{2}{x-2}$
then $$f(g(x))=\frac{1}{(g(x)-11)(g(x)-6)}$$
After some computation, $f(g(x))$ has a,
Removable Discontinuity at $x=2$,
Infinite Discontinuity at $x=24/11$ and $x=7/3$
Now, Clearly, $g(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=2$ so is $f(g(x))$
also, $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=11$ and $x=6$ and $g^{-1}(11)=24/11$, $g^{-1}(6)=7/3$
So, $f(g(x))$ is discontinuous at $x=24/11$ and $x=7/3$.
Is the above result generalized and works for all composite functions?
[Note: $g^{-1}(x)$ denotes $g$ inverse of x]

No. Take $f = g = \chi_\mathbb{Q}$, the indicator function of $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$, i.e.
$$
  f(x) = g(x) = \begin{cases}
      1 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
      0 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}
  \end{cases}
$$
$f$ and $g$ are discontinuous everywhere, but clearly $f(g(x)) = 1$ for all $x$ as $g(x) \in \{0, 1\} \subset \mathbb{Q}$, so $f \circ g$ is continuous everywhere.

Is this the drichilet function? And if I add a condition that $f \not= g$ then will it be true? @bensteffan


It is. 2. No, it won't: Take $f = \chi_\mathbb{Q}$ and $g = 2 \chi_\mathbb{Q}$.

